# Missing space with mxmlElementSetAttr command C

Tags: c, xml, mxml

I have some troubles with mxmlElementSetAttr.
I'm using this command several times in my source code, but the result is not really stable.
Here is a part of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mxml.h>

char *FiletoBuf(char *FileName)
{
    char    *buffer;            
    size_t  i;                  
    size_t  buffer_size;        
    char    *temp;              
    char    c;                  
    FILE    *input;             
if ((input = fopen(FileName, "r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file %s\n", FileName);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

i = 0;
buffer_size = 1024;
if ((buffer = malloc(buffer_size)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory (before reading file).\n");
    fclose(input);
}

while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
{
    // Enlarge buffer if necessary
    if (i == buffer_size)
    {
        buffer_size += 1024;
        if ((temp = realloc(buffer, buffer_size)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of core while reading file.\n");
            fclose(input);
            free(buffer);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buffer = temp;
    }

    if (c != '\n' && c != '\t')
        // Add input char to the buffer if not Line Feed or Tabulation
        buffer[i++] = c;
}

if (ferror(input))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "There was a file input error.\n");
    free(buffer);
    fclose(input);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (i == buffer_size)
{
    buffer_size += 1;
    if ((temp = realloc(buffer, buffer_size)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of core.\n");
        fclose(input);
        free(buffer);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer = temp;
}

buffer[i] = '\0';

fclose(input);


return buffer;
}

void test()
{
FILE        *fp;
mxml_node_t *xml = NULL;
mxml_node_t *msg = NULL;
char        *Buffer_Resp;
int         i;

xml = mxmlNewXML("1.0");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    msg = mxmlNewElement(xml, "param");
    mxmlElementSetAttr(msg, "name", "test");
}

if ((fp = fopen("Test.xml", "w")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file %s \n", "Test.xml");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else
{
    mxmlSaveFile(xml, fp, MXML_NO_CALLBACK);
    printf("File %s has been created. \n", "Test.xml");
}

if (fp)
    fclose(fp);

Buffer_Resp = FiletoBuf("Test.xml");
remove("Test.xml");

if (xml)
{
    mxmlDelete(msg);
    mxmlDelete(xml);
}

printf("%s", Buffer_Resp);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv )
{
    test();


return 0;
}
```

The results is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><param name="test" /><paramname="test" /><param name="test" /><param name="test" /><paramname="test" />
```

Sometimes it's 'param name' (which is correct) and sometimes it's 'paramname' (which is not...).

And you can note that there's a space before the '/>' characters.
Anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you simplify your code down to only do exactly what you've shown us? This has the earmarks of a character-pointer manipulation error, unless you've got a badly broken XML serializer (in which case the fix would be to upgrade to most recent).

Comment: I edited my code. Hope it will help you (and me by the way...)